# How to hide Opera's address bar in current tab (hotkey)?

Tags: hotkeys, opera, address-bar

What is the hotkey for hiding the current's tab address bar ?

In the older versions of Opera it has been done by `Ctrl + F8` [link1](http://allhotkeys.com/opera_hotkeys.html) or [link2](http://www.opera.com/browser/tutorials/nomouse/)but they have somehow changed it and I cannot find the information.

I use Opera 11.62 (on windows 7)

Comment: You should give some information, like which OS and which exact version. I don't know the answer, but that might help someone who may.

Comment: @zielak's answer should work get your shortcut back. If you're just after adding some extra screen real estate (otherwise why would you want the address bar gone?), you can just toggle full screen view on and off by pressing `F11` (in case you didn't know already).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This hotkey works when you're using *Opera 9.2 Compatible* keyboard setup. You can also [add](http://help.opera.com/Windows/11.60/en/input.html) this shortcut to your current settings:

Press *Edit*, set new shortcut `ctrl f8` and action `Set alignment, "document toolbar", 6 | Set alignment, "document toolbar", 0` into *Browser Window*.

But I'm afraid it works in all tabs.

Comment: Really nice hack :P but can you explain it a little ?

Comment: @Patryk it's default action from _Opera 9.2 Compatible_ settings.

Comment: I know but it's not in the newest 11.62 version.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [official help](http://help.opera.com/Windows/11.50/en/keyboard.html), there is no such a feature right now. There was [before](http://help.opera.com/Windows/9.24/en/keyboard.html), but right now it's just not there.

Answer (score 1):

Go to "preferences - shortcuts - edit -  Browser Window" and set hotkey, shortcut and action.

Action for Show\Hide adress bar:

Set alignment, "document toolbar", 6 | Set alignment, "document toolbar", 0

Action for Show\Hide bookmark bar:

Set alignment, "personalbar inline", 6 | Set alignment, "personalbar inline", 0

Action for Show\Hide tab bar:

Set alignment, "pagebar", 6 | Set alignment, "pagebar", 0

Answer (score 1):

As of February 2023, this feature is no longer available in Opera browser. I did quite a lot of research but could not find this functionality in settings section. I am using the following Opera version:

**Opera version:** 89.0.4447.51